# ¿Como puedo llamar un metodo en Java?

Tags: java, contador

Antes que nada agradecer a los que se tomen su tiempo para ayudarme a resolver este breve problema que tengo en java/eclipse, intentaré ser breve y conciso.

Estoy tratando de hacer un juego de piedra papel y tijeras(ejercicio que es de programación básica) y en el ejercicio quisiera aplicar un contador que me lleve la cuenta de cuantas partidas se han jugado, cuantas lleva ganado/perdido la máquina, cuantas lleva ganado/ perdido el usuario y cuantas han salido en empate.

Quiero mantener el programa simple y con mis errores de principiante, ya el programa está casi terminado el problema me surge cuando trato de imprimir la información de los contadores, para ello hice un método llamado score y le pase los parámetros para que solo tenga que imprimir el mensaje, aquí les dejo una parte del código:

```java
    public static void score(int contadorJugadas, int contadorPerdidasPc, int contadorPerdidasUsuario, int contadorGanadasPc,int contadorGanadasUsuario,int empate) {
        
            System.out.println("Partidas Jugadas en Total = " + contadorJugadas);                                                       
            System.out.println("Partidas que Gano el Jugador 1: (PC) = " + contadorGanadasPc);                          System.out.println("Partidas que Gano el Jugador 2: (Usuario) = " + contadorGanadasUsuario);                                        
            System.out.println("Partidas que Perdio el Jugador 1: (PC) = " + contadorPerdidasPc);                       System.out.println("Partidas que Perdio el Jugador 2: (Usuario) = " + contadorPerdidasUsuario);                                 
            System.out.println("Partidas que terminaron en Empate = " + empate);                        

}
```

de momento todo perfecto, ahora llega les mostrare un poco mas de mi codigo para que tengan contexto, este es el menu del programa que se ejecuta en un bucle while, try..

```java
public static void menu(Scanner sc) {

        boolean salir = false;
        while (!salir) {

            try {
                int pcOpcion = (int) (Math.random() * 3) + 1;
                System.out.println("1. Jugar ");
                System.out.println("2. Instrucciones");
                System.out.println("3. Historial");
                System.out.println("4. Salir");
                int opcion = sc.nextInt();

                switch (opcion) {

                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Selecciona una opcion: ");
                    System.out.println("\n        _______________________" + "\n          |        PIEDRA       |   "
                            + "\n         |           1         |" + "\n          |_____________________|"
                            + "\n         |        PAPEL        |" + "\n          |           2         |"
                            + "\n         |_____________________|" + "\n          |        TIJERAS      |  "
                            + "\n         |           3         |" + "\n          |_____________________|");

                    int usuarioOpcion = sc.nextInt();
                    if (usuarioOpcion > 3) {
                        System.out.println("Ingresa un valor entre 1 y 3");
                    } else {
                        juego(usuarioOpcion, pcOpcion, sc);
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Instrucciones del juego:" + "\nJuego de Piedra Papel o Tijeras vs Maquina : "
                            + "\nEl juego consiste en escoger un numero del 1 al 3, la maquina tambien escogerá un número aleatoriamente y despues se compararan resultados, ¡Que gane el mejor!"
                            + "\n1 = piedra, 2 = papel , 3 = tijeras." + "\nRoca rompe tijera" + "\nPapel cubre la roca"
                            + "\nTijera corta el papel");
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    score(contadorJugadas,contadorPerdidasPc,contadorPerdidasUsuario,contadorGanadasPc,contadorGanadasUsuario,empate);
                    System.out.println("");
                    break;
```

Hasta aquí les muestro el código porque creo que mostrarles más sería redundante y no creo que sea necesario para resolver el problema(en caso de que así hacérmelo saber y os lo subiré completo)

Pero bueno, como pueden ver la parte que nos importa es el caso 3 del switch que es la opcion historial de mi menu, deberia llevarme hasta el metodo que cree llamado score y mostrarme el texto que he escrito, pero no me deja, el programa me pide que declare las variables y esto ya me complica el programa, porque ¿donde tengo que declararlas? ¿hay alguna forma mas facil de pasar los parametros?

Aqui les dejo una ultima parte del codigo, es otro metodo, que es donde se ejecuta el juego y se decide quien gana, pierde o empata, y se le suma al contador correspondiente

```java
public static void juego(int usuarioOpcion, int pcOpcion, Scanner sc) { // Hemos creado este metodo para facilitar
                                                                            // la lectura y ejecucion del programa, aqui
                                                                            // se ejecutan las reglas del juego y se
                                                                            // decide el ganador.

        // La forma en la que usamos el switch es primero haciendo que la máquina escoja
        // un valor aleatorio entre 1 y 3 y acorde a eso se abrirán unas opciones para
        // el usuario, dependiendo de los valores que tome se decidirá el resultado.

        int contadorJugadas = 0, contadorPerdidasPc = 0, contadorPerdidasUsuario = 0, contadorGanadasPc = 0,
                contadorGanadasUsuario = 0, empate = 0;
        switch (pcOpcion) {
        case 1:
            System.out.println("PC = Piedra");
            // Eleccion del Usuario
            switch (usuarioOpcion) {
            case 1:
                empate++;
                contadorJugadas++;
                System.out.println(" ____________________\n" + "|      EMPATE!       |  \n"
                        + "|____________________|   \n" + "Piedra vs Piedra");
                menu(sc);
                break;
```

Si tienen alguna duda o no he expresado claramente mi problema, les pido por favor que me lo comenten para corregir los errores, gracias de antemano de nuevo al que me ayude, soy un programador principiante y me gustaría aprender de ustedes, un saludo.

Comment: Pues obviamente que tienes que declararlas. Primero, porque al ser un método estático no tiene acceso a los atributos de tu clase que no sean estáticos, y segundo porque esas variables están declaradas en otro método. Si tu amigo se compra un telescopio, tú desde tu casa puedes usarlo para ver las estrellas?? No verdad? Tienes que ir a su casa a acceder a él, o él tiene que llevarlo a la tuya. Es básicamente lo mismo. O le pasas todas las variables que tiene que usar, o las guardas todas en un lugar común (instancia de la clase). Pero entonces tus métodos no podrían ser `static`...

Comment: ... así que lo más fácil será que pases las variables por parámetro al método que las va a necesitar. Y si te parece complicado, te recomiendo que lo hagas. Porque si no haces algo básico porque es complicado, cuando realmente llegues a las partes más complicadas vas a tener un déficit en la base y no vas a poder avanzar. En programación es tan necesario aprenderse la base como en matemáticas aprender a sumar y restar. Todo evoluciona a partir de ahí y son cosas que siempre vas a usar.

Answer (score 1):

El problema esta en que las variables las estas declarando dentro de la función `juego`, entonces todas las variables que declares dentro de dicha función no están declaradas en el propio método `menu`, lo que hace imposible acceder a ellas.
La solución mas rápida sería declararlas en `menu` y pasarlas como parámetro tanto al método `juego` como al método `score`.
Tal que así:

```
public static void menu(Scanner sc) {

int contadorJugadas = 0, 
int contadorPerdidasPc = 0, 
int contadorPerdidasUsuario = 0, 
int contadorGanadasPc = 0,
int contadorGanadasUsuario = 0, 
empate = 0;
//AQUI SIGUE TU CÓDIGO
```

y luego en el método `juego` se los pasas como parametros:

```
public static void juego(int usuarioOpcion, int pcOpcion, Scanner sc, int contadorJugadas, int contadorPerdidasPc, int contadorPerdidasUsuario, int contadorGanadasPc,
            int contadorGanadasUsuario, int empate) {
```

Y para temrminar la llamada a tu metodo jugar

```
juego(usuarioOpcion, pcOpcion, sc, contadorJugadas, contadorPerdidasPc, contadorPerdidasUsuario, contadorGanadasPc,
            contadorGanadasUsuario, empate);
```